# PHP hit counter scaling issue

Tags: php, html, web, counter

I have 3 php pages.

Counter.php - Display's how many clicks page Counter2 and 3 got.

```
<?php
  session_start()
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
     Counter2 <?php  echo $_SESSION["counter2"]; ?> Times.
     <p></p>
     Counter3 <?php  echo $_SESSION["counter3"]; ?> Times.
</body>
</html>
```

Counter2.php - Records how many clicks this page has had.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["counter2"])) #v1
{ $counter2 = $_SESSION["counter2"]; } #v2
else
{ $counter2 = 0; } #v1
$_SESSION["counter2"] = $counter2 + 1; #v2
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?= $counter2 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Counter3.php - Records how many clicks this page has had.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["counter3"])) #v1
{ $counter3 = $_SESSION["counter3"]; } #v2
else
{ $counter3 = 0; } #v1
$_SESSION["counter3"] = $counter3 + 1; #v2
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
  You visted this page this many times: <?= $counter3 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**THE PROBLEM:
For everynew counter page I make, it means I have to add that code snippet in (Which you can see below Counter2 and 3). I do not want to be having to do that. Is there anyway I can add a code to one page so it calculates what all of the counter pages get individually then displays it on Counter.php ?**

Best regards,

Comment: take a look at include http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Did you know that session is per user storage? How can you count views with session? Does your script even work, because it can't, visit that counter from another IP where session is not set :) For counting views, clicks, and visits [ for this you can use session, but it's more preferable to use cookies ] you should use something like database storage.